# How to keep player position after collision?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

Im making a game in canvas and I have included a library to deal with collision for me.
The collision is working perfectly, but I am not really sure how to "freeze" the player in place and not allow movement in that direction after colliding. Can anyone help me out ?

What I tried :

```js
  moveRight() {
    this.pp.x = this.position.x;
    this.position.x += 20;
  }
  moveLeft() {
    this.pp.x = this.position.x;
    this.position.x -= 20;
  }
  moveUp() {
    this.pp.y = this.position.y;
    this.position.y += 20;
  }
  moveDown() {
    this.pp.y = this.position.y;
    this.position.y -= 20;
  }
```

I tried keeping track of "previous position" and set it to that on collision, but it's behaving really strange, doesn't really work.

Ideally, I would like to make a stop() function in my player class that I would call upon player colliding with the world.

Thanks so much, any help is greatly appreciated ! ! !

I use lib (https://github.com/RonenNess/SSCD.js/)to do the collision testing for me, here is the code :

```js
export function collisionDetection(game) {
  let world = new SSCD.World({ grid_size: 1024 });
  let player = new SSCD.Rectangle(
    new SSCD.Vector(game.player.position.x, game.player.position.y),
    new SSCD.Vector(game.player.width, game.player.height)
  );
  let zombie = new SSCD.Rectangle(
    new SSCD.Vector(game.zombie.position.x, game.zombie.position.y),
    new SSCD.Vector(game.zombie.width, game.zombie.height)
  );
  let walls = game.walls;
  walls.forEach(wall => {
    world.add(
      new SSCD.Rectangle(
        new SSCD.Vector(wall.position.x, wall.position.y),
        new SSCD.Vector(wall.width, wall.height)
      )
    );
  });

  if (world.test_collision(player)) {
    game.player.speed = 0;
    return 
}
```

Comment: You should show the collision-detection code too (does it work with rectangular tiles, free-form tiles, free-form paths?). Showing the directional-controls is not enough, because the functionality you want needs both.

Comment: It's a third party library, It uses rectangular tiles ! Thank you for the answer, I have included the code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A low-budget approach is to update the coordinates in a loop (so instead `x+=10`, do an `x++` 10 times), and "undo" the change when a collision occurs, see the unnamed function at the very end (the one passed to `setInterval()`):

```js
function range(l,x,h){
  return l<=x && x<h;
}
function rnd(r){
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*r);
}
function Rect(x,y,w,h){
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.w=w;
  this.h=h;
}
Rect.prototype.draw=function(ctx){
  ctx.strokeRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);
};
Rect.prototype.contains=function(x,y){
  return range(this.x,x,this.x+this.w) &&
    range(this.y,y,this.y+this.h);
}
Rect.prototype.intersects=function(r){
  return this.contains(r.x,r.y) ||
    this.contains(r.x+r.w,r.y) ||
    this.contains(r.x,r.y+r.h) ||
    this.contains(r.x+r.w,r.y+r.h);
}
const player=new Rect(1,1,10,10);
const walls=[];
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
  let x=rnd(200);
  let y=rnd(200);;
  walls.push(new Rect(x+20,y+20,rnd(250-x)+10,rnd(250-y)+10));
}
function collide(){
  if(player.x<=0 || player.y<=0 ||
     player.x+player.w>=300 || player.y+player.h>=300)
     return true;
  for(let i=0;i<walls.length;i++)
    if(walls[i].intersects(player))
      return true;
  return false;
}
const ctx=cnv.getContext("2d");
function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.strokeRect(0,0,300,300);
  ctx.strokeStyle="#0000FF";
  for(let i=0;i<walls.length;i++)
    walls[i].draw(ctx);
  ctx.strokeStyle="#00FF00";
  player.draw(ctx);
}
draw();

const keymap=[false,false,false,false];
addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
  if(range(37,event.keyCode,41))
    keymap[event.keyCode-37]=true;
});
addEventListener("keyup",function(event){
  if(range(37,event.keyCode,41))
    keymap[event.keyCode-37]=false;
});

setInterval(function(){
  for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(keymap[0]){
      player.x--;
      if(collide())
        player.x++;
    }
    if(keymap[1]){
      player.y--;
      if(collide())
        player.y++;
    }
    if(keymap[2]){
      player.x++;
      if(collide())
        player.x--;
    }
    if(keymap[3]){
      player.y++;
      if(collide())
        player.y--;
    }
  }
  draw();
},100);
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

"Game" is supposed to respond to the arrow keys, even multiple ones can be pressed simultaneously. Also, use "Full page", after starting, as it does not fit in the box here, and the arrows would wildly scroll everything around anyway. Oh, and it needs clicking on the canvas once.

---

I saw the edit too, and I think you could check the https://github.com/RonenNess/SSCD.js#resolve-penetration-or-penetration-prevention part from that page, and experiment with `repel()`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to have `20` as a `property` of your class. This property would be a "`speed`" property. You can then access it using "`this.speed`". Once you detect a collision set the speed to `0` and you will "freeze" your character.

For example moveRight would become

```
moveRight() {
    this.pp.x = this.position.x;
    this.position.x += this.speed;
  }
```

Comment: Just tried it, the problem is my character gets "stuck" to the wall. After colliding I am unable to move in any direction

Comment: What is the requirement? I understood you wanted the character not to move upon collision?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad! Well I dont want the character to move through walls yes, but by doing this by setting speed to 0 it stays at 0 and I cant move again. Thanks for the answer!